# Adding class to images in rich text

Tags: redactor

How can I add a CSS class to all images inserted into a rich text field ?

ie. so an image inserted has style= "image fit" added to the img selector

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wrote a plugin called [Retcon HTML](https://github.com/mmikkel/RetconHTML-Craft) which will solve this nicely using PHP's [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) class.

You'll want to use the `attr` filter, which is documented [here](https://github.com/mmikkel/RetconHTML-Craft/wiki/Attr):

```
{{ entry.richTextField | retconAttr( 'img', { 'class' : 'image fit' }) }}
```

Comment: This is a really clean solution, thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

I found this to work quite well for adding Bootstraps "img-fluid" class automatically:

```
{{ entry.yourTextField|replace('<img ', '<img class="img-fluid" ')|raw }}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a plugin that's supposed to do what you want: [Redactor Add Attributes](https://github.com/nilsenpaul/redactoraddattributes/), but unfortunately it doesn't work with Craft newer that 2.0 (which includes the completely refactored Redactor 10).

Comment: Nope, sorry for that. If anyone has the time to make the necessary adjustments, I'd be more than happy to update the plugin.